# "Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined" even though it is bound

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I'm trying to just test that a function is indeed invoked when a click action occurs on a link in my component. I keep receiving the error `Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined`. But this function from another file is bound to the constructor in the component.

The component

```
import { toggleEditMode } from './otherFile.js'
class PersonalInformation extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {editMode: false}
    this.toggleEditMode = toggleEditMode.bind(this);
  }

  render(){
   const { editMode } = this.state;
   return(
     <div>
{!editMode &&
            <div className="col-md-4 hidden-sm-down">
              <a
                id="editingToggleButton"
                className="display-block"
                role="button"
                href="javascript:void(0);"
                onClick={() => this.toggleEditMode()}
              >
                <span className="icon icon-sm dls-icon-edit" />
                <span className="pad-1-l">Edit</span>
              </a>
            </div>
          }
     </div>
    )
  }
}
```

The toggleEdit method

```
export function toggleEditMode() {
  this.setState({ editMode: !this.state.editMode })
}
```

The test

```
describe('edit', () => {
  it('should switch to editMode with click', () => {
  const toggleEditMode = jest.fn();
  const wrapper = mount(
    <PersonalInformation
      toggleEditMode={toggleEditMode}
    />
  );
    wrapper.find('#editingToggleButton').simulate('click');
    expect(toggleEditMode).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
}
```

When it renders the error it specifically points to `this.setState` within the toggleEdit function.

Comment: remove this before toggleEditMode in constructor

Comment: By reproducing it in a codesandbox, I get the expected behavior : https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-nobel-b2nsx

Answer (score 1):

Here is the problem

You bind the function in the constructor, but you use it as an arrow function.

What you should do is add the bind in the arrow function or only pass the function reference.

```
this.toggleEditMode = toggleEditMode.bind(this);
// and 
onClick={this.toggleEditMode}
```

OR

```
// remove .bind from the constructor
this.toggleEditMode = toggleEditMode
// and 
onClick={() => this.toggleEditMode.bind(this)}
```

But I think you should use the first case, because the second case will recreate the arrow function on every render.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use reactjs [hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-overview.html) to change the state

here is the demo.

```
function PersonalInformation() {
  const [editMode, changeEditMode] = useState(false);
  function toggleEditMode() {
    changeEditMode(!editMode);
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <span className="pad-1-l" onClick={toggleEditMode}>
        {!editMode
          ? `Not Editable (click to change)`
          : `editable(click to change)`}
      </span>
    </div>
  );
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/embed/determined-benz-c5km7